# How to fix overflow error when testing with Hardhat

Tags: hardhat

I'm getting an BigNumber overflow error when running hardhat tests. How do I fix this?

```
const ownerBalance = await MyToken.mint(
   owner.address,
   "ipfs://".length,
   { value: ethers.BigNumber.from(50000000000000000) }
);
```

Comment: Hello. Please provide the complete error with stack trace.

Comment: make sure that '50000000000000000' is a string

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the error from the `BigNumber` part, then I suggest you construct the number like this: `ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", 16)`.